# Perl for-loop not working as expected

Tags: perl, for-loop

I've been teaching myself Perl for the past couple weeks. For practice, I've been going through problems over at projecteuler.net. I've got a pair of nested for-loops that aren't working as expected. For context, the problem is to find the largest palindromic number that is the product of two 3-digit numbers. Here's my code:

```
sub isPalindrome($)
{
    return 0 if length($_[0]) <= 1;
    $reverse = reverse $_[0];
    $_[0] == $reverse ? return 1 : return 0;
}

sub findPalindrome{
        for($i = 999; $i >= 100; $i--)
        {
            for($j = 999; $j >= 100; $j--)
            {
                print "$i\t$j\n";
                return ($i, $j, $j * $i) if(isPalindrome($j * $i)); #return the two factors followed by their product#
            }
        }   
}

($factor1, $factor2, $product) = findPalindrome();


print "$factor1 * $factor2 = $product\n";
```

My problem is that sub findPalindrome is not working as expected. I'm find a palindromic number, but not the highest; it's like it's skipping something in the loop. To try and track down the problem, I inserted the line of code above to make it print out each pair of numbers it iterates through, and it looks like it's iterating properly. My guess is that for-loops in Perl work differently than I'm used to in C++; either way, I'm lost. What am I missing?

Edit: The answer I'm getting is "995 * 583 = 580085", which is indeed a palindromic number, and the multiplication is correct, but it's the wrong answer according to Project Euler. On a whim, I changed the for loops in `sub findPalindrome` to iterate through 999 to 900, and that gave me the correct answer ("993 * 913 = 906609"). For some reason, when the bottom of the range is 100, it fails to find the answer; when the bottom of the range is 900, it does find it.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It finds your error.

Comment: If it iterates properly, why do you think loop works differently?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker - It's iterating properly, but the answer it gives me is wrong; either something's wrong with my for-loop, or it's something else in my code that I can't find.

Comment: What is the number you get and what is the number you expect?

Comment: I'm getting '995 * 583 = 580085' with your code, as-is...  that seems pretty early in the sequence to me.   I'm with Michael, what answer are you expecting, why do you think it's skipping?

Comment: @TimA, I'm not with me anymore, after finally reading problem description ;)

Comment: Note that in the inner loop, you don't need to loop through 100 to 999. Just loop from `$i` to 999. (FWIW, this is [my solution](https://gist.github.com/tobyink/8249398).)

Comment: You should really have `for( my $i = ...`

Comment: @tobyink, I think it's more fun to iterate in the proper order instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally read the problem description on top of your question ;) Your loop is not iterating in the desired order. For example `998*998` is encountered after `999*100`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I got caught up in the code and missed the problem with the math. Thanks!

Comment: good catch. maybe run through the entire sequence, collecting the answers and the number it took to get them, and then sort and report the highest...

Comment: I don't think this is the most elegant way. Though the whole fun is to find the way, I think the OP will want to play with it himself ;)

Comment: Agreed. I will make a suggestion, though: think about which is faster, finding all products of _n_ x _m_ for _n_ and _m_ in [100,999], or finding all the palindromic numbers between 10,000 and 998,001.